# less-rails-bootstrap ... where are the less files

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, less

I don't know if this is a ridiculous question however I am creating a website with RefineryCMS, Ruby, and Rails. I chose to speed up some things by using Twitter's Bootstrap via the less-rails-bootstrap gem. I do however need to customize some colors and such though I can't seem to locate any of the less files. I looked in the logs and see references to things such as 'twitter/bootstrap.css' though I'm not able to locate this or where the less files live.

Where are these things? Else, how to do you override the defaults?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you complete with gem install and `bundle install` command , you should :

```
rails g bootstrap:install
```

This will insert some files in your `app/assets` dir , including `bootstrap_and_overrides.css.less` in `app/assets/stylesheets`.

You can learn more in [this Railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/328-twitter-bootstrap-basics?view=asciicast).

UPDATE: (Jan 25 2014): Valuable information form the comment of @Niels Abildgaard:

According to [GitHub repository](https://github.com/metaskills/less-rails-bootstrap/blob/master/README.md) of `less-rails-bootstrap` gem, Rails generator command shoud be :

```
rails generate less_rails_bootstrap:custom_bootstrap
```

Comment: This appears to have worked for me though I have to add that I have to run `bundle install` twice. Not entirely sure why. The first time I ran it the new styles showed though the call you indicated failed. After running it again all was well.

Comment: Sometimes is like this - try and fail . But the pleasure of nice done work is really great . Good luck , Rig .

Comment: Rails tells me that it cannot find the generator when doing this.

Comment: According to the project on GitHub you should run `rails generate less_rails_bootstrap:custom_bootstrap` (worked for me). Source: https://github.com/metaskills/less-rails-bootstrap/blob/master/README.md